# How do I render an array/list of checkboxes in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have an array of objects, and I want a checkbox for each row, how do I do that in Rails?

```
-@txns.each do |txn|
  %tr
    %td= checkbox_tag txn.processed?
```

I want to create HTML like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="txn_42" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="txn_43" />
<input type="checkbox" name="txn_44" />
```

I tried a few things in the console, but it doesn't seem right.

```
irb(main):015:0> ApplicationController.helpers.check_box_tag 'txnDetail[]', txn.processed, txn.id
=> "<input checked=\"checked\" id=\"txnDetail_\" name=\"txnDetail[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" />"


irb(main):009:0> ApplicationController.helpers.check_box_tag :txnDetail, :processed, txn.id, txn.processed
NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys' for true:TrueClass
```

Reference

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't seem right"?  Are you having a specific issue?

Comment: How is the controller going to know which row is checked upon submission if the id is not included in the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I found an undocumented feature. It will 'parse' the given name, extract an index, use that for the id, and use that when submitting parameters.

```
%td= check_box_tag "txnDetail[#{txn.id}]", true, txn.processed # name, value, checked?
```

When rendered, it looks like this:

```
<input checked="checked" id="txnDetail_13" name="txnDetail[13]" type="checkbox" value="true" />
```

When submitting, it looks like this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"check", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "txnDetail"=>{"4"=>"true"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

It can be processed in the controller like this:

```
txns = params[:txnDetail] || {}
txns.each do |key, val|
  td = TxnDetail.find(key)
  if val == 'true' # HTML submits strings
```

Answer (score 1):

from [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag)

`check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})`

And you want like this
`<input type="checkbox" name="txn_42" checked/>`

So I think this would do the trick-->

```
-@txns.each do |txn|
  %tr
    %td= checkbox_tag txn.id, txn.id, txn.processed?
```

Comment: `checkbox_tag "txn_#{txn.id}", txn.id, txn.processed?`  


here `txn.id` will become id of the checkbox and `txn.processed?` will decide if checkbox is selected or not

Comment: Ok. Is that standard Rails? Will I have to parse all of the parameters to get the id? It generates: `"<input checked="checked" id="txn_13" name="txn_13" type="checkbox" value="13" />"`.

Comment: Sorry my bad... corrected now... Now it will generate following `"<input checked="checked" id="13" name="13" type="checkbox" value="13" />"` You can use this id to access them in controller

Comment: The second param to `checkbox_tag` specify the value so if you don't plan to use you can use following
  `%td= checkbox_tag txn.id, nil, txn.processed?`